# Make my game moddable

Tags: java, api

I want to make my Java game moddable. I was thinking about Lua but I don't like this idea too much. Basically I just want to make API for my game that'll contains some methods that will be available for people making mod. After I make the mod I want to somehow compile it into a jar file. The most tricky part is to load the file (mod) as a mod. I've never done anything like that, but I've created some mods for game Minecraft using Minecraft Forge API so I know that it's possible.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind.... Write a class loader that loads jars at runtime from a 'plugins' or 'mods' directory. Have the mods implement some common interface.

Comment: Another minecraft-cubic guy nah...

Comment: Of course. :) But I'm not making Minecraft-like game. :) It's just example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make my Java game moddable.

IMO, the best way to do this is to make the complete source-code of your program available freely to anyone who wants it.

But assuming that you mean "mods" to your game that don't involve people hacking on the core code, there are standard ways of implementing "plugin" functionality in Java.  Basically, you structure your application so that the areas where you want the behaviour to be "mod-able" have:

- a well designed `interface` that "mod" coders can implement,
- a plugin loader that finds and loads custom code (mods) from somewhere, and
- some kind of registry mechanism that allows your application to find the code.

In addition, making the code open source makes it a lot easier for mod coders to code and debug their mods.  If they can see the core code, they can figure out how they need to write their code to interact with it.

Comment: Yes, but I want to make the game supports multiple mods at once and leave the game open-source is not the solution for that.

Comment: @Samuel - It is not the solution.  But I think it is **part** of the solution.